# Experiencing Lag With Blender

Tags: interface, performance, opengl

## Issue

I've experienced lag when viewing in the viewport window, selecting objects', and moving selected objects'.

## Attempted Solutions:

- Adding more computer RAM (previously **8gb**, now **64gb**)
- Reinstalling Blender
- Turning off OpenGL Depth-Picking in the User Preferences

## Observations:

The issues always happens over time, while at first there is no lag, no matter how simple or complex the scene is.

## Computer Specs

Minus the said RAM upgrade:

OS: Windows 11 Home (15-dy2024nr, Natural silver)
Brand: HP 15-inch Laptop
CPU: 11th Generation Intel Core i5-1135G7
GPU: Intel Iris Xe Graphics
RAM: 8gb (now 64gb)
SSD: 256gb

## Conclusion

I forgot to mention it's just about everything that slows Blender down when I'm using it. So, again, scene complexity is not a contributing factor to my lag I think.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Blender's Requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/), your config alone shouldn't have issues other than lacking an actual GPU, but that would impact mostly rendering, not usage.

You don't tell which Blender versions you are using, so I suggest you to make sure you have the latest stable 3.0. If it is still not working, try the latest [nightly 3.1 alpha](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/).
If you still encounter issues, consider going to the menu `Help` > `Report a Bug`.

Comment: ok, doing that now, ill give you an update, it may not be today that is gets done, my wifi i have at my parents house is shit

Comment: update

works fine, left it open on a simple scene and it is good, i guess 3.0 just hates my pc?

Comment: another update, it just takes longer for it to kick it and start lagging